# How do I setup my host machine's PHP interpreter to point to the container's PHP interpreter

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

I would like to configure PHPStorm so that I can run Artisan commands directly from my IDE's terminal. For example `php artisan key:generate`. However, when I do, I receive the error `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Background:

- running Windows 10 as host machine
- using Docker to run my webserver (Nginx) and PHP interpreter (7.2-fpm).
- I followed this tutorial. 
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose.

One thing the tutorial didn't cover was how to set up my remote PHP CLI interpreter. For that, I followed https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html and can make a successful connection as it picks up the correct PHP version *7.2.21* as seen in the screenshot.

[image: Remote PHP CLI Interpreter]

After this, I restarted my Windows 10 host machine, fired up the container, opened my IDE and tried to run `php -v` from the terminal but hit the error again.

[image: PHP interpreter not found]

I know it has something to do with my *PATH* environment variable being set incorrectly, or not at all but I am not sure how to point it to the container's PHP interpreter. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

For what it is worth, I know that I can `exec` into the container and run PHP commands from there, but thought I might be able to do it directly from my host machine by pointing to the container's interpreter.

[image: <code>exec</code> + PHP commands]

Comment: I guess the `PHP executable` reference would need updating from the system-wide `php` to the container php?

Comment: Tried `whereis php` which gave me 4 locations: `/usr/local/bin/php`, `/usr/local/etc/php`, `/usr/local/lib/php`, `/usr/local/php`. Tried each one and restarted IDE inbetween but same result.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; How would the php inside the container access files outside of it?

Comment: Same way as it does now - through a volume mount. My PHP files are sitting locally on my host machine and the container has a mount pointing them. You may be right though that it is not possible but the documentation (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html) makes it sound like it should be.

Comment: You can run them with `docker exec`. What I do is create an alias: `alias dockerphp="docker exec nameofcontainer php"` then run `dockerphp artisan whatever`.

Comment: Neat idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal in PHPstorm is the same as any other terminal on your computer. It doesn't automatically connect to docker to run the `php -v` command. If you want to run php from PHPstorm in docker you can right click the file:

Choose run:

[image: Run action]

And select your created docker interpreter as your runtime:

[image: configure the interpreter]

If the fix button doesn't show it can be configured through:

```
settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP
```

And then clicking on the 3 dots at the end of "CLI interpreter"

Comment: When I run `php -v` from PHPStorm's terminal, shouldn't it use the interpreter that I defined in the "CLI Interpreters" section? I realize this wouldn't apply to other terminals such as PowerShell.

Comment: No it shouldn't because that terminal is the same as any other terminal such as powershell. You can configure your webserver or runner from PHPstorm to use the docker environment. @waterloomatt

Comment: @MaartenDev how can i configure php-cli to work in terminal using docker? My IDE is PHPStorm